Nushell: List directories first, including symlinks to directories
Using Nushell I want ls to list directories before files. Additionally, I want symbolic links to be sorted correctly: If it is a link to a directory, it should be included in the list of directories. And if it is a link to a file, it should be in the list of files.
I developed the following script:
let is_dir = {|file|
    $file.type == 'dir' or ($file.target | to text | str ends-with '/')
};

let dirs = ls --all --long
    | filter $is_dir
    | sort-by name --ignore-case;

let files = ls --all --long
    | filter {|file| not (do $is_dir $file)}
    | sort-by name --ignore-case;

$dirs ++ $files
    | select name

But that seems to be too much code for such an easy request.

Can the code be simplified somehow?
1.1 Is there a better way to find out whether the symlink points to a directory? Using $file.target | to text | str ends-with '/') was the only way I saw, but I'm not proud of that solution.
1.2 Also, filter {|file| not (do $is_dir $file)} is not the best code I ever wrote. How can I do that better?
Is there a better approach to achieve the same?

This question is about Nushell, not other shells. :-)

Note that there are a few potential problems in your code above.  I say "potential", because if it's working for you, perhaps your use-case just doesn't require them.

The target for a symlink to a directory doesn't necessarily end in /. It simply depends on whether or not the trailing slash was used when creating the symlink.  ls -l / to see that the default Linux (at least on Ubuntu) symlink targets don't include trailing slashes.

Nushell ls (like a normal /usr/bin/ls or even eza) doesn't resolve the "final" target of a symlink-to-a-symlink (or further nested).  I can't think of an "easy" built-in Nushell way (other then a recursive technique) to resolve the final target, but you always have the option of dropping in realpath on non-Windows platforms.

As far as I can tell, your implementation only works if run in the current directory.  Attempting to use it on another path with ls <path> probably won't work, as $file.target doesn't return a fully-qualified path.


Regardless, here's a version that handles all of the above.  It's fairly compact, and definitely fits the Nushell structured-data paradigm. It works by inserting a new column into the ls table with the type of the target (or actual file/dir) and sorts the results based on that.
ls -l
| insert sort-type {|f|
    match $f.type {
      # For symlinks, use the type of the target
      symlink => ( $f.name | path expand | ls -D $in | get type.0 )
      # Otherwise just use the type:
      _ => $f.type
    }
  }
| sort-by sort-type name
| reject sort-type

Note that there's a new sorting feature to allow closures in sort-by, which adds an additional implementation possibility, but I'm not sure that will be any easier than the option above.

Thank you for your tips and pointing out the problems with my code. That helps.  :-)
